# How to append the df to a another df in a process of loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This code gets the data and the data is made into a loop and that runs until the loops gets completed.

So i need to append the data to a df that stores the data after every process complete

code :

```
a = "SELECT id FROM USER WHERE time >'2018-03-01'"
dataa = pd.read_sql_query(a, con=engine)
print(dataa)

for userid in dataa:
   x=f"SELECT idbody FROM col1 WHERE user_id='{userid}'"
   data = pd.read_sql_query(x,con = engine)
```

so here data gets is processed and  data every time  produced is different need to append the data to a df that stores all the data that gets processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loop or by list comprehension append values to `list` and only once use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
a = "SELECT id FROM USER WHERE time >'2018-03-01'"
dataa = pd.read_sql_query(a, con=engine)

dfs = []
for userid in dataa:
    x=f"SELECT idbody FROM col1 WHERE user_id='{userid}'"
    data = pd.read_sql_query(x,con = engine)
    dfs.append(data)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
dfs = [pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT idbody FROM col1 WHERE user_id='{userid}'",con = engine) 
       for userid in dataa]

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you get same number of columns, and those columns have the same names.
e.g. This is the basic idea:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()  # this will hold your all data

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])  # 1st iteration data
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(11, 22, 33)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])  # 2nd iteration data
df3 = pd.DataFrame([(111, 222, 333)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])  # 3rd iteratin data etc.

for data in [df1, df2, df3]:
    df = df.append(df1)

     a    b    c
0    1    2    3
1   11   22   33
2  111  222  333
```

What you need to do is:

```
a = "SELECT id FROM USER WHERE time >'2018-03-01'"
dataa = pd.read_sql_query(a, con=engine)
print(dataa)

df_all = pd.DataFrame()  # create an empty df to store all returns
for userid in dataa:
    x=f"SELECT idbody FROM col1 WHERE user_id='{userid}'"
    data = pd.read_sql_query(x,con = engine)
    df_all = df_all.append(data)  # update df with new dframes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `concat`:

```
a = "SELECT id FROM USER WHERE time >'2018-03-01'"
dataa = pd.read_sql_query(a, con=engine)
print(dataa)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for userid in dataa:
    x=f"SELECT idbody FROM col1 WHERE user_id='{userid}'"
    data = pd.read_sql_query(x,con = engine)
    df = pd.concat([df_all, data])
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Would be the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach, instead of looping, why not join all `userid` into one string, and make one call to the database using SQL `IN` statement:

```
a = "SELECT id FROM USER WHERE time >'2018-03-01'"
dataa = pd.read_sql_query(a, con=engine)

userids = ', '.join([f'"{x}"' for x in dataa['id'].astype(str).values])
x = f"SELECT idbody FROM col1 WHERE user_id IN ({userids})"

data = pd.read_sql_query(x,con = engine)
```

#### Example

```
dataa = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['123', '124', '125', '126']})

userids = ', '.join([f'"{x}"' for x in dataa['id'].astype(str).values])
x = f"SELECT idbody FROM col1 WHERE user_id IN ({userids})"
print(x)
```

[out]

```
# SELECT idbody FROM col1 WHERE user_id IN ("123", "124", "125", "126")
```